# Arduino Uno Keeps Resetting (Power issue)

Tags: arduino-uno

Arduinites!

Hoping you can help a newbie. I'm putting together a board for a Christmas present this year. It's replacing the factory board that comes on a beer fridge/vending machine, with minimal interactions.

Basically, when the beer can falls into an outlet chute, it trips a switch that triggers some LEDs and audio. Pretty simple stuff. The fridge supplied +5v to the previous board, so I thought I could remove it and simply swap in the Arduino.

The code runs fine when the Arduino is powered by USB/laptop. I spliced a USB header onto the +5v wire supplied by the fridge and plugged it all in. Now, it will boot up, play some weird fuzz out of the speaker, and reset after about 10 seconds.

How can I use the +5v to power my nutty creation? The previous board had a capacitor on it which I removed (I know next to nothing about some of this stuff but it seems like maybe that would help?)

Here's a photo of what I'm working with. If I need to provide any additional information or photos I can do that.

[image: My board]

[image: Fridge Schematic]

[image: Power]

[image]
If you have any advice, please ELI5 with regards to what I might be able to place in my circuit to get this working (links or definitions are incredibly helpful!)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Without knowing the specs of the power supply it's impossible to tell. It may only have a very low current capacity, or it may be unsmoothed, or similar.

Comment: @Majenko thanks for the reply. what's the best way to determine more information about the specs? Multimeter?

Comment: First step is to examine the power supply and see if there are any clues. Second step is probably to monitor the power with an oscilloscope looking for brownouts.

Comment: Holy jumper wires, Batman!  It might help if you used ribbon jumpers, so you can make sure you don't have an accidental short somewhere.

Comment: @computercarguy haha, thanks for the recommendation! You're right, that would definitely clean up the board. Everything works fine when plugged in to my computer, so although it definitely looks a little unwieldly I'm sure it's wired alright for now.

Comment: @Majenko I've added some photos from the back of the fridge (informational) and a pic of the power supply board and transformer. In your mind, does this shed any additional information as to why this is happening?

Comment: I think @Majenko is on the right track. It's probably a noisy and/or low current power supply.

You also mentioned the old board had a capacitor on it, which makes me suspicious. What happens if you add a capacitor (say 470uF, 16V) across the 5v supply? That capacitor may have been smoothing out the supply, especially with an electrically-noisy compressor nearby.

Comment: @toxicantidote thanks for the reply. Where exactly would I add the capacitor? Seems like it would need to somehow be added somewhere before the 5v hits the Arduino, yes?

Comment: The main problem here is the current IMHO. The IC on the power supply is a 78L05, which provides at most 100mA. The arduino itself can drain around 30mA; each LED can be around 20mA (you did not specify how many and how much current they absorb), and the audio board is usually hungry. So I think that 100mA are not enough. You can confirm this by measuring the current when it works. Are you forced to use that power supply? Otherwise take a small cheap USB charger (1-2$) and you will have something like 1A+ of available current

Comment: @frarugi87 thanks for the reply. I don't _have_ to use it as a power source but it is certainly the cleaner option if I can figure out how to make it work! I have 8 LEDs on the board along with the audio chip, so I could see it being underpowered, but I guess I don't understand why it would work when plugged into a laptop USB and not this source.

Comment: @DaveKiss well, a (recent) laptop USB usually can provide at least 500mA (or even more, if it has some USB3 ports). If it is a current issue, I don't think you can solve it with just a capacitor (BTW, use a large electrolytic capacitor rated at 10V or more; connect the pin labelled "-" to the ground and the other to +5V - but don't invert the pins!!! Explosion risk). But maybe it is worth trying. In any case, another supply rated at 1A or more in my opinion will solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

How much current takes your board with all components? Maybe the 5V power supply can not give you the wanted current.

- You can use a oscilloscope to see what is happening with the 5V when you use your board (maybe not enough current) for example interruptions on your connection or the voltage is not stable.
- Maybe you can find a datasheed for the power supply for more information
- try your board with another power supply to see if this is a problem of the board or the power supply

I just recognized in the third picture that the transformers output have 5V and 200mA. Your speaker will maybe have 8 Ohm (please write us the resistance). This means it will take 5V/8 Ohm this equals a current of 0,625 or 625mA. This current is 3 times higher than the output current of the transformer.

My theory 1 is:

Your circuit worked on your computers USB because you have got usb 3.0 and the max current for it is 900mA wich is much greater than 625mA and enough for leds, speaker and arduino. Your speaker is not connected directly to a pin and gnd. Some seperate electronics manages the pulses and takes directly the 5V of the USB.

My theory 2 is: 
You used USB 2.0 (500mA) or USB 3.0 (900mA) and the speaker is connected directly to a pin (the resistance is ok or you added some resistance). The sound was probably not loud because the power was low. The current for both USBs were enough for leds, speaker and arduino.

Now to your problem with the resetting.

The solution:

Switch off the speaker and test your circuit without it. (I think it will work fine).

If it works: You took too much current and this current heated the pin and  influenced the charecteristics of the pin and finally the voltage at your pin (weird fuzz). Add a variable resistor in series to your speaker an try it.

If it not works: Measure the output voltage of the transformer and wirte us the value.